# I'm working on a website that i have to print a bill , but i wanna do that silently without print preview

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, printing

I've searched and seen different question on stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem. I've used .Net and javaScript on my website. Can anyone provide a solution or tell me it is better to make it in JavaScript or in C#

Comment: You won't be able to do that; browsers simply don't allow it.

Comment: Imagine surfing the web and your browser starts printing 100s of black pages. If it is an internal thing, I am sure there are better was of doing it with  a custom print system.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not going to happen in a browser. Browser's are extremely touchy to us doing anything without the user's consent. Hence accessing their printer without their knowledge is way out of the question.

Comment: I agree with comments above however - if you have control over the environment (I had to do something similar but for a Point Of Sale) website which was running on the LAN and we did that using FiddlerCore and identified the print job (a PDF file returned from server) and printed it silently.

Comment: @Digvijay Can you provide me a link or solution because its totally my case

Comment: I do not have the fiddler based code handy - else i would have posted that. Here is anothet link i found relevant : https://github.com/jrichardsz/poc-print-from-browser

For fiddlercore look here : http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore

Comment: @Digvijay thank you very much but i fixed locally in my chrome by fixing some stuf there and now it print automatically

Comment: @Anonymuslegacy - Good to hear!